# Adjacent sibling selectors in less

Tags: css, less

Hi how to convert adjacent sibling selectors from css to less

Example:

```
#block .tall + p {
    [some attributes]
}
```

If I convert this to less like so

```
#block {
    .tall {
        + {
              p {
                }
          }
    }
}
```

I get ***ParseError: Unrecognised input in + {***

When I try to use `&+& {` in conversion back to css it becomes

```
#block .tall + #block .tall p
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: `#block {
 .tall + p {
  [some attributes]
 }
}`

Comment: @Banzay Thanks worked like charm! Write this as answer this will definitely will help others ;)

Comment: You don't need to "convert" it. `#block .tall + p { [some attributes] }` is already perfectly good LESS.

Comment: @torazaburo I converting this back to css to check if its exactly same css, thanks anyway

Comment: What's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
#block { 
    .tall + p {
        [some attributes] 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `p` on the same line as the `+`

Otherwise you are saying adjacent to nothing and the p is the child of that adjacent nothing:

```less
#block {
  .tall {
    + p {}
  }
}
```

[Example CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdJXPW)